# How to find max using pyspark fold operation in following example?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and python. So, please help me with this problem where i need to find max value using fold and by using `operator.gt` or by writing our own `lambda` function.

Following code written by me throws error that rdd cannot be indexed. I understood it but how to pass and compare values each value 1,2,0,3 with 0 and find max.
Here 0 is my accumulator value and 1,2,0,3 are current values each time.
I am trying to convert a program written in scala that explained fold to python.
Answer expected :  `('d', 3)`

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from operator import gt

def main():
    sc = SparkContext("local", "test")

    data = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 2),('c', 0), ('d', 3)])

    #dummy = ('dummy', 0)

    maxVal = data.fold(0, lambda acc, a : gt(acc, a[1])).collect()

    print(maxVal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you understand what lambdas are and how `fold` works?
Another hint: What you need is not actually a simple maximum (although it will involve calculating a maximum), because you don't need only the maximal value but the whole row containing the value.

Answer (score 2):

- Use [neutral value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) (a one which can be merge an arbitrary number of times without changing the final result) suitable for a particular operation and matches the type of data (the function should be [`(T, T) => T`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%40fold%28zeroValue%3AT%29%28op%3A%28T%2CT%29%3D%253ET%29%3AT) or with Python conventions [`Callable[[T, T], T]`](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs/blob/232a6e07959330cbe726e5cf6939a557287e996c/third_party/3/pyspark/rdd.pyi#L101)). With `max` by value it makes sense to use `float("-Inf")` and a dummy key:

  ```
  zero = (None, float("-Inf"))
  ```
- To reduce use `max` with `key`:

  ```
  from functools import partial
  from operator import itemgetter

  op = partial(max, key=itemgetter(1))
  ```

Combined:

```
data.fold(zero, op)
```

```
('d', 3)
```

Of course in practice you can just use `RDD.max`

```
data.max(key=itemgetter(1))
```

```
('d', 3)
```